# ListFragment gives ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Tags: android, android-listfragment

I'm trying to implement a simple list/detail view as in figure 1 [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) but I'm getting a "Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'" runtime exception. This error seems to have been discussed at length if the amount of results is anything to go by, but most of the answers seem to be about extending ListActivity whereas I'm extending ListFragment. So far I've had no luck in getting it fixed. The base activity is:

**SpeciesListActivity.java**

```
public class SpeciesListActivity extends MenuItemActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_species_list);

        // Check if the species_detail view is available. If it is
        // we're running both fragments together.
        if (findViewById(R.id.species_detail) != null) {
        }
    }
}
```

The fragments are included via its layout file:

**activity_species_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment android:name="com.example.fragments.SpeciesListFragment"
            android:id="@+id/species_list"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <fragment android:name="net.gamebreeder.fragments.SpeciesDetailFragment"
            android:id="@+id/species_detail"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the two pane layout, the single pane one is the same except for the second fragment (id species_detail) not being included.

The fragment in question:

**SpeciesListFragment.java**

```
public class SpeciesListFragment extends ListFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_species_list, container, false);
    }
}
```

And the fragment's layout:

**fragment_species_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp">

    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>

    <TextView android:id="@id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/empty_string"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I've tried changing SpeciesListFragment to not override onCreateView() to force it to use the defaults, since according to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html):

> Note: If your fragment is a subclass of ListFragment, the default implementation returns a ListView from onCreateView(), so you don't need to implement it.

But I still get:
`java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'`

One question I found suggested I ensure that I'm extending FragmentActivity in the main activity and that's exactly what MenuItemActivity is:

```
public class MenuItemActivity extends FragmentActivity {
```

It's basically just a wrapper so I don't have to manually create the menu in every activity.

Any help would be appreciated - I'm hoping I'm just missing something simple.

**Edit 2013-06-27**

I've tried formatting the id in the fragment_species_list.xml as both `@id/android:list` and `@android:id/list` but neither work. The docs say to use `@id/android:list` but the other questions I've read seem to suggest that both should work but I get the error with both. I've tried with `@+id/list` as well.

I've also changed the following based on the answers below:

**activity_species_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment class="com.example.fragments.SpeciesListFragment"
            android:id="@+id/species_list"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <fragment class="net.gamebreeder.fragments.SpeciesDetailFragment"
            android:id="@+id/species_detail"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly caused this but I managed to solve it by deleting all the old fragment, activity and layout files which were originally created with an ADT eclipse template.

I basically re-wrote everything from scratch, one piece at a time to ensure everything is getting called correctly. I suspect that this was simply due to all references not being updated in the compiled code despite cleaning out all the compiled code numerous times (both manually and with the eclipse project clean tool).

Answer (score 7):

Add this include to your list layout:

```
<include layout="@android:layout/list_content" />
<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/list" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white" />
```

This worked for me....

Documentation on android site: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html

> public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup
>   container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
>
> Added in API level 11 Provide default implementation to return a
>   simple list view. Subclasses can override to replace with their own
>   layout. If doing so, **the returned view hierarchy must have a ListView
>   whose id is android.R.id.list** and can optionally have a sibling view
>   id android.R.id.empty that is to be shown when the list is empty.
>
> ***If you are overriding this method with your own custom content,
>   consider including the standard layout list_content in your layout***
>   file, so that you continue to retain all of the standard behavior of
>   ListFragment. In particular, this is currently the only way to have
>   the built-in indeterminant progress state be shown.

Answer (score -2):

Your  fragment_species_list.xml should be as follows. you had "@android/id:list" should be "@id/android:list"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="8dp"
android:paddingRight="8dp">

<ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>

<TextView android:id="@id/android:empty"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/empty_string"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I forgot to add it to my question, but I've tried that before. I've just tried it again and it's still not working.

Comment: hmmm weird did you try adding a break point at onCreateView for SpeciesListFragment to make sure that it is being called?

Comment: I am on confused about your implementation. Seems like your trying to have both a phone and tablet layout. If that is the case you should have two fragment_species_list.xml for phone and one for the tablet

Comment: I've added loggin calls throughout the entire thing to ensure everything gets called. In the end I basically just re-wrote the entire thing. I'm adding the answer now.

Answer (score -2):

just replace this xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment class="com.example.fragments.SpeciesListFragment"
        android:id="@+id/species_list"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<fragment class="net.gamebreeder.fragments.SpeciesDetailFragment"
        android:id="@+id/species_detail"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I've made this change as well, but no luck. I'm still getting the same error. I've also tried it in combination with your other suggestion of changing the id to `@+id/list` but that isn't working either.

Answer (score -2):

This may be because your are using

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
```

try giving

```
 <ListView android:id="@+id/list"
```

Comment: oh! may be just clean build your project to see any error in any of the .xml files. This happens to me sometimes and usually the reason is some feable error in an xml .

Comment: Since started getting this error I force clean the project before every compile and the XML files aren't showing any errors :(

Comment: remove the R.java and start the project again :( sorry !

Answer (score -3):

check ur fragment_species_list.xml , there

```
 <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>
```

in ur listview, the id should be android:id="@+id/list"

Comment: make two changes in ur activity_species_list.xml

Comment: i just add one answer, replace ur current xml file with this one

Comment: I'm not following - which two changes should I make?