# R.layout.activity_find_contact cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: android

I am brand new to android development so please bear with me. I have encountered a problem when I create a new activity. In the newly created activity there is the auto-generated overridden method 'onCreate':

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_find_contact);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    setupActionBar();
}
```

On the line `setContentView(R.layout.activity_find_contact);`, I get the error: `activity_find_contact cannot be resolved or is not a field`.

I have looked up other questions on this topic. Some say to just restart eclipse - this didn't work. Others said to try cleaning the project - this didn't work either. The most promising answer said to delete the line:

`import android.R;`

I tried this, and of course then `R` gets the error: `R cannot be resolved to a variable`. So I followed the advice to import `your.application.package.R;` - which in my context translates to `import com.example.databasetest.R;`. However this just brings up the error `the import com.example.databasetest.R; cannot be resolved to a type`.

So now I'm stumped and back to square one. Any ideas?

Comment: do you create activity_find_contact.xml inside res/layout ?

Comment: there is some error in your res folder (Xml file) . firstly check that & from project clean your project .

Comment: Check your activity_find_contact.xml file Is there any error there...

Comment: Can u please show your xml content??? I think there is an error in your xml.....

Comment: @blackbelt Yes, I have created my activities as per the google starting tutorial: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html I have the activity_find_contact.xml file inside res/layout.

Comment: Your question title is misleading, it is your layout and not your Activity which cannot be resolved error..

Comment: look in the Problems Bar. the error should be listed there

Comment: Make sure you don't have any errors in your manifest file - or the resources will not be built correctly.

Comment: Well asked question. @Teifi If you get import errors on com.packagename.R, then first check the problem view and see if there any error in the files inside your res/ folder.  If you don't have problem view visible by default, select `Menu-> Window->Show View->Problems` as of eclipse Juno.

Comment: Did you build your project ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17327397/listfragment-gives-listview-whose-id-attribute-is-android-r-id-list/17340305#17340305

Comment: Can those who have down-voted this question please explain why. My question conforms to SO standard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

R files are automatically generated.. so you don't need to import it or do anything. The error is because there is something wrong in your xml file or files.Got through your xml files and see if you can find any errors.

These errors might even be typos.So make sure all of it is correct and cleaning and running the project again should get your code working

Comment: I checked my activity xml files and there were no errors (hence why I was confused). The problem was actually in my **strings.xml** file - there was an error I had not seen.

I had the following line `<string name="null"></string>` which I was using as an empty string. However, despite the `null` part being inside quotes, the compiler really did not like the word 'null'. I changed it to 'nulls' and my strings.xml file was then fine - which meant that the rest of my errors dissapeared.

Comment: That's great :).. That's why i specified in my answer XMl file or files. It can be any xml file strings,value,acvtivity etc which gives that error..

Answer (score 2):

Do not use the following import

```
import android.R;
```

This errors comes because when we create new app we delete hello world textview but that is referenced in strings.xml in res > values > strings

go to that and remove hello world , clean project and errors should be gone ...